# Why is keyword not being rendered?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got the following. All works well. But `{{keyword}}` in `app/templates/search/results.hbs` is not being rendered at all...

Any pointers?

```
// app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('search', { path: '/search' }, function() {
    this.route('results', { path: ':keyword' });
  });
};

// app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    search: function(keyword) {
      this.transitionTo('search.results', keyword);
    }
  }
});

// app/routes/search/results.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      products: this.store.find('product', { name: params.keyword, status: 'available' })
    });
  }
});

// app/templates/application.hbs
<form {{action "search" keyword on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="text" value=keyword placeholder="search" class="search"}}
</form>

// app/templates/search/results.hbs
<h3>Searching "{{keyword}}"</h3>
{{product-list products=products action='addToCart' fromRoute='index'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyword property belongs to application controller since binded in `application.hbs` template to use the same property in your `results.hbs` template you need to provide the binding to it in your controller.

```
//results controller
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    keywords: Em.computed.alias('controllers.application.keyword')
});
```

Comment: In an ember-cli app. So had to change `Em.computed.alias('controllers.application.keyword')` to `Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.keyword')`. Still doesnt render anything...

Comment: @ChristianFazzini can you setup a jsbin for it?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini I tried it in js bin and it was working....
See this: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nuhihejezu/1/edit?html,js
But you have to go to search/results route i.e. `#/search/<<somekeyword>>`

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yibodababe/1#/search/adsfadsfasdf If you type,the keyword is rendered in the template. But if you refresh or go directly to the link. The keyword is not reflected

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @guleria, it is better to use the renderTemplate to render the search views into the application template using outlets, this way all search views will be managed by a single controller

```
// app/routes/search/results.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    search: function(keyword) {
      this.transitionTo('search.results', keyword);
    }
  },
  setupController: function (controller) {
    var params = this.paramsFor(this.routeName);
    controller.set('keyword', params.keyword);
  },
  renderTemplate: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.render('searchbar', {
      into: 'application',
      controller: controller,
      outlet: 'searchbar'
    });
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      products: this.store.find('product', { name: params.keyword, status: 'available' })
    });
  }
});

// app/templates/searchbar.hbs. Note: after the render it will be controlled by searchController
<form {{action "search" keyword on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="text" value=keyword placeholder="search" class="search"}}
</form>

// app/templates/search/results.hbs
<h3>Searching "{{keyword}}"</h3>
{{product-list products=products action='addToCart' fromRoute='index'}}


// app/templates/application.hbs
{{outlet 'searchbar'}}
{{outlet}} {{! in our example this will be the outlet of the search view}}
```

Comment: this is much better approach though

Answer (score 0):

simply, this would do what you expect

```
App.SearchResults = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      products: this.store.find('product', { name: params.keyword, status: 'available' }),
      keyword : params.keyword
    });
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/jekimudaki/2/edit?html,js)

Comment: `keyword` feels like a property though.. Does it really belong there? Setting it up like that, tries to put in within the model definition. What do you think?

Comment: IMO, when considering the separation of responsibilities, `keyword` is the property of the `SearchResults` controller, should not belongs to `Application`. I'd also prefer to place the `search` action within `SearchResults` route or controller as @g13013 pointed.

Comment: Right, I agree with all those principles. But `keyword` doesn't belong to `Application`. It is only used there so that it can pass the value to another route/controller.